# Await a nested function wrapped by a sync func Javascript

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, form-data

The prompt is quite simple but I was not able to figure out a solution, unfortunately.

I have to file a create API then update API. Normally, I can do promise, async/await, or even callback. However, the createAPI is wrapped by a formData function(getLength) since it needs to attach a file. Because of that, I'm not able to await the inner API before firing off an update.

Since getLength does not return anything and it's not a promise, I'm not sure how I may be able to work around this? Thank you!

```
const createFunc = async () => {
    formData.getLength(async (err, length) => {
        await platformAPI
            .createAPI(formData, length)
            .then((res) => {
                if (res !== 201) {
                    console.log("something went wrong")
                }
                console.log("it works") 
            });
    });
}


const apiFunc = () => {
    createFunc().then(() => updateApi())
}
```

Comment: `getLength` appears to use a callback, you can convert callback's into Promises,..  eg. in node there is one in utils -> https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original  Or you can even use the Promise contructor pattern to convert the callback into a promise.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise

Comment: "*getLength does not return anything and it's not a promise*" - fix that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can *promisify* `formData.getLength`. Either use Node's [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) to get the promisified version of `getLength`, or else promisify it yourself, like this:

```
// Promisify getLength:
const promiseLength = formData =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        formData.getLength((err, length) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(length))
    );

const createFunc = () =>
    promiseLength(formData).then(length =>
        platformAPI
        .createAPI(formData, length)
        .then(res => {
            if (res !== 201) console.log("something went wrong")
            else console.log("it works"); // Only print this in the else-case
            return res; // Better return the value
        });
    );
```

Note that `async` is not of much use when the only statement in that function is an `await`. In that case just return the awaited expression and drop the `async` keyword. And your second use of `async` does not even have an `await`... so that is useless.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed. My bad. I had something on the second await but forgot to remove it when I posted the question just to simplify my use case. Anyways, thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Promise` constructor to convert `.getLength` to a Promise-based API, which you can then `await`:

```js
const createFunc = async () => {
    const length = await new Promise ((rs, rj) => {
      formData.getLength((err, length) => {
        if(err)
          rj(err);
        else
          rs(length);
      });
    })
    //This part with the `then` was OK, but since you're already using `async/await`, there's no reason why you shouldn't use it here too
    const res = await platformAPI.createAPI(formData, length)
    if (res !== 201) {
      console.log("something went wrong")
    }
    console.log("it works")
}


const apiFunc = () => {
    createFunc().then(() => updateApi())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you separate your implementation because **formData.getLength** function not a promise function. You shouldn't use callback and await all together. I think that not a good practice. if we can use await use always that format its much more cleaner.

```
const getLengthFunc = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  formData.getLength((err, length) => {
    if(err)
      reject('error');
    
    resolve(length)
  }
});

const createFunc = async () => {
  try{
    const length = await getLengthFunc();
    const res = await platformAPI.createAPI(formData, length);

    if (res !== 201)
       console.log("something went wrong")
            
    console.log("it works")
  }catch(e){
    console.log(e)
  }
}


const apiFunc = () => {
    createFunc().then(() => updateApi())
}
```